# change to another image when click imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I set an image A for imageview of item in listview. I set the onclick event and change to another image B. But after clicking it can not change to another iamge. When I print Log I see this method has been called.

```
holder.bus_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bus_blue);
            holder.bus_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("i", "点击图标了+test11" + position);
                    holder.bus_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bus_red);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: dont call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` because you nothing changed in adapter and call `holder.bus_icon.invalidate();`.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the onclick, the holder is pointing to wrong imageView.

Use this instead

```
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("i", "点击图标了+test11" + position);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bus_red);
                }
```

Hope it solves